# Can I divide two alias columns in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, alias, division, integer-division

I'm trying to get the percentage of times something occurs (a task requires an outbound call)

So I made a count distinct of the occurrence "CALLED THE CUSTOMER" and aliased it as **outbound_calls**. And counted all the tasks alias **"total_tasks"**

These two steps work and I get this

[image]

Now I'm trying to divide outbound_calls by total_taks to get the percentage but get an error saying that the name oubound_calls is not recognized

This is the query I'm writing

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(Out_CONTACT_TYPE = 'CALLED THE CUSTOMER', booking_id, NULL )) AS outbound_calls,
COUNT(task_id) AS total_tasks,
DIV(outbound_calls, total_tasks)
FROM `cs-reporting...`
```

Any ideas?

Happy Friday :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help.

You can use a subquery in this case :

```sql
SELECT 
   outbound_calls,
   total_tasks,
   DIV(outbound_calls, total_tasks)
FROM
(
  SELECT
   COUNT(DISTINCT IF(Out_CONTACT_TYPE = 'CALLED THE CUSTOMER', booking_id, NULL )) AS outbound_calls,
   COUNT(task_id) AS total_tasks
  FROM `cs-reporting...`
)
```

You can also use a `WITH` bloc :

```sql
WITH reporting AS
(
    SELECT
     COUNT(DISTINCT IF(Out_CONTACT_TYPE = 'CALLED THE CUSTOMER', booking_id, NULL )) AS outbound_calls,
     COUNT(task_id) AS total_tasks
    FROM `cs-reporting...`
)

SELECT 
   outbound_calls,
   total_tasks,
   DIV(outbound_calls, total_tasks)
FROM reporting;
```

For divisions with `BigQuery`, you can use `SAFE_DIVIDE` with `ROUND` functions (example with 2 digits) :

```sql
SELECT 
  outbound_calls,
  total_tasks,
  ROUND(SAFE_DIVIDE(outbound_calls, total_tasks), 2) as divres
FROM
(
SELECT 
   5 as outbound_calls,
   3 as total_tasks
);
```

According to the [BigQuery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#alias_visibility) the aliases are visibles in the `from` not in the `select` bloc directly.

Comment: Thanks @Mazlum. Now the "plot thickens" the result of the division is 0 even if I cast it as a float I get 0.0 when I know it should be around 0.48. Any suggestions

Comment: You're welcome, can you give me an example of values for `outbound_calls` and `total_tasks`, and I give it a try :)

Comment: I updated my answer to give you an example of division with `BigQuery`. May you add an upvote to make my answer more valuable please ?

Comment: Hey, you are so kind :) I have 127222 outbound_calls and 263729 total_tasks